# Wordpress select and crop in plugin

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, size, crop

I needs to upload images in my plugin and use wp.media for this task. 
According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media

Its work, but I needs to have "Select and Crop" option in media library after upload my image with custom size.

I was see this in default theme in appearence custom header image, but can't understand how I can use this in my plugin with wp.media js?

Answer (score 0):

This my not be better solution but work in wordpress :)
i use [Thumbnail Crop Position](https://wordpress.org/plugins/thumbnail-crop-position/screenshots/) and [Simple Image Sizes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/) for that :)
Good luck! :)

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 the_post_thumbnail('yourImageSize'); 
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer posted here that does Select and Crop using the Media Library on a theme options page. You can use it as a starting point for getting it to work in a plugin:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281760/using-media-uploader-to-select-image-of-specific-size-enforce-cropper/302962#302962